# Android - unable to add data to arraylist of string - when data retrieved from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a custom list adapter that has many methods that query the database and add data to different java objects or lists.

code to consider in adapter as follows: -

```
static class ViewHolder {
    ArrayList<String> imgUrls;

    //other variables;
}
```

then initiated it in  getView method as:-

```
public View getView(@params) {
    holder.imgUrls = new ArrayList<>();
}

//i have a method that query and retrieve data from firebase as follows:-
public void getPhoto(final ViewHolder holder) {
    Query query = reference
            .child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_collections))
            .child(holder.collection.getCollection_id())
            .child("photo_url");
    query.keepSynced(true);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                imgUrl = singleSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: imgUrl: " + imgUrl);
                holder.imgUrls.add(imgUrl);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    Log.d(TAG, "getPhoto: list with values " + holder.imgUrls);
}
```

My database in firebase console look like this:-

```
{
  "collections": {
    "-L9nNSyF7ZhEqpvmPo0Z": {
      "caption": "jakhaha",
      "collection_id": "-L9nNSyF7ZhEqpvmPo0Z",
      "date_created": "2018-04-11T11:55:57Z",
      "photo_url": [
        "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/backbench-72a47.appspot.com/o/collection%2Fusers%2FHb8ORoozQ3WhyxjaSyqazjHypkf2%2F2018-04-11T11%3A55%3A57Z%2Fphoto0?alt=media&token=08fdb740-9b16-455b-83ec-bfcec1455834",
        "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/backbench-72a47.appspot.com/o/collection%2Fusers%2FHb8ORoozQ3WhyxjaSyqazjHypkf2%2F2018-04-11T11%3A55%3A57Z%2Fphoto1?alt=media&token=eeca4b10-0729-4ca9-be18-c31d054add19",
        "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/backbench-72a47.appspot.com/o/collection%2Fusers%2FHb8ORoozQ3WhyxjaSyqazjHypkf2%2F2018-04-11T11%3A55%3A57Z%2Fphoto2?alt=media&token=b33c97b0-c2bf-4199-bef0-b498f505a678"
      ],
      //this are the imageUrls i want to retrieve as a arrylist
      "tags": "#NoTags",
      "user_id": "Hb8ORoozQ3WhyxjaSyqazjHypkf2"
    }
  }
}
```

in my firebase model class :-

```
public class Collection implements Parcelable {

    //properties for photo (*case sensitive*)
    private String caption;
    private String date_created;
    private String collection_id;
    private String user_id;
    private String tags;
    //list of likes
    private List<String> photo_url;
    private List<Like> likes;
    private List<Comment> comments;

    public Collection() {

    }

    //constructor..getter setters etc...

}
```

in my log console i see that values of imgUrl are fatched

```
04-11 20:35:03.992 21269-21269/com.backbenchers.administrator.instaclone D/CollectionListAdapter: onDataChange: imgUrl://url of image 1
 onDataChange: imgUrl: url of image 2
    onDataChange: imgUrl: ...image 3
```

but it shows list as null or [] :-

```
D/CollectionListAdapter: getPhoto: list is with values : []
```

"I want to fetch this firebase data and add it to an arraylist.."

what is wrong ??

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the design of your data flow is flawed. The Adapter will instantiate and reuse the ViewHolder instances in an unpredictable way, so putting data you retrieved into a pre-determined ViewHolder instance is bound to result in broken behavior. I would recommend doing the Firebase data retrieval outside of the adapter (good for separation-of-concerns as well), and then set the retrieved data onto the Adapter.

Comment: @theFunkyEngineer is right here. collect the data from firebase. use the model for the setters within a for loop. from tthere, you can use this list to fill up your list adapter.